# Retrieve data from url into json format in flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am trying to retrieve data from url into json format using flask-restplus.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, fields
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# config details
COLLECTION = 'indicators'

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(
  app,
  title='Akhil Jain',
  description='Developing ' \
  'a Flask-Restplus data service that allows a client to ' \
  'read and store some publicly available economic indicator ' \
  'data for countries around the world, and allow the consumers ' \
  'to access the data through a REST API.'
)

@api.route('/indicators')
def get(self):
        uri = 'http://api.worldbank.org/v2/indicators'
        try:
            res = requests.get(uri)
            print(res)
            return res.json()
        except:
            return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but after trying out the GET, the response i am getting is False instead of the json data.
Could anyone tell me how to get the response data so that i can process it to sqllite db.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like http://api.worldbank.org/v2/indicators response is not json

Comment: @a.l. yes, i think it is XML

Comment: thus `return res.json()` would raise an Exception which would make your app response `False`

Comment: did the solution that i provided work ?.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the content from response

If you would want to save the xml data then.

```
try:
            res = requests.get(uri)
            print(res.content)
            return res.content
         except:
            return False
```

If you want to save it as json, then install module xmltodict.

```
try:
            res = requests.get(uri)
            jsondata = xmltodict.parse(res.content)
            print(jsondata)
            return jsondata
         except:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to retrieve an XML producing endpoint. - Invoking `json` will raise an exception since the content retrieved is not `json`.

The ideal way of doing this is to build a function that parses the data as per your requirements; the example below can be treated as a reference.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as element_tree
xml = element_tree.fromstring(response.content)

for entry in xml.findall(path_here, namespace_here):
    my_value = entry.find(attribute_here, namespace_here).text
```

You can opt to use `lxml` or other tools available. - The above is an example of how you can parse your `xml` response.